# Write/Read Binary Savegame

Tags: c, file-io, save, load

I'm currently working on a save and a load program so, but I'm having trouble getting the correct result.

Write program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILENAME "Save"
#define COUNT 6

typedef struct
{
  unsigned Activeplayer;
  char row[7];
} Savegame;

int main()
{
char rowA[7]={'A','-','-','-','-','-','-'};
char rowB[7]={'B','-','-','-','-','-','-'};
char rowC[7]={'-','-','-','-','-','-','-'};
char rowD[7]={'-','-','-','-','-','-','-'};
char rowE[7]={'-','-','-','-','-','-','-'};
char rowF[7]={'-','-','-','-','-','-','-'};
int activeplayer = 2;

Savegame product[COUNT] = {{ activeplayer, rowA},
                         { activeplayer, rowB},
                         { activeplayer, rowC},
                         { activeplayer, rowD},
                         { activeplayer, rowE},
                         { activeplayer, rowF},
                         };

FILE *output = fopen(FILENAME, "wb+");
if (output)   // file opened OK
{
int written = fwrite(product, sizeof(Savegame), COUNT, output);
printf("%d records written to file.\n", written);
fclose(output);
}
return 0;
}
```

Everything compiles fine and it creates a binary file.
Then I wrote another program which should print out the rows and the Activeplayer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILENAME "Save"
#define COUNT 6

typedef struct
{
  unsigned Activeplayer;
  char row[7];
} Savegame;

int main()
{
 FILE *input = fopen(FILENAME, "r");  // read
 Savegame *temp = (Savegame*) malloc(sizeof(Savegame));
 if (input)   // file opened OK
{
 while (fread(temp,sizeof(Savegame),1,input))
{
    printf("%s: %d\n",temp->row,temp->Activeplayer);
}
}
  free(temp);
  fclose(input);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program, it doesn't show me the rows from program A, but instead different characters.

I know that there are probably many mistakes in the code, but I'm still a beginner, so really any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't store rows but "pointers" of them. Name of the table is some kind of constant pointer. Try saving it more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have wrote the file in binary. You should read the file in binary mode. 
Try this :

```
FILE *input = fopen(FILENAME, "rb");  // read
```